# Value of items in a c# listbox

Tags: c#, arrays, listbox

I am sure if i look hard enough i can find my answer but so far i can't find a clear cut answer.

What i am trying to do is use the value of an item in a listbox which contains 7 items as a numerical identifier for a specific array element. (all items in the list are strings)

```
array[listbox.value] = my new data for that array element
```

i know i can pull the string of the item out but and that i can identify a specific item in the list with.

```
list1.Items[value].ToString();
```

i just want to know if i can do reverse the alternative is a pain to code as its a lot more lines of code comparing the string in the list to each item in my array until i find a match while i know all items in the list are the same order as the array.

Comment: Are the values in the listbox integers?

Comment: no they are strings ie Item1, Item2...

Comment: @MattFarrell I don't really understand your question. If you want to access to the array from the selected value in the ListBox you can use the property listBox1.SelectedIndex that give you the index selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an array, you can use a dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, valueType> myArray = new Dictionary<string, valueType>();
myArray["Item1"] = some value
myArray["Item2"] = some value
```

... etc

Then later

```
myArray[listbox.Value.ToString()] = my new value
```

Thats really the best way to refer to an array index by a string value. The type for the indexer does not necessarily need to be a string, it can be any type that is uniquely identifiable.

Comment: thats interesting but the way iv gone about i have multiple arrays not all containting the same thing but array1[5] contains data while array[5] contains a name that relates to the data i know i could of done this more effectivly but iv gone too far to turn back now

Comment: You may need to explain better what you need to do then, what you are asking for isn't possible, array indexers are always integers. Also, don't ever be afraid to throw stuff out and start again, I've literally taken projects with over 10k lines of code and tossed them out the window because I got "too far to turn back" and things were getting more and more difficult by the day.

Comment: that may soon be the case. simply put i am asking is there a way to get the numerical identifier out of the list as i am sure one exists as i can point to an item by specifying listbox1.items[x]

Comment: You can get the SelectedIndex but it isn't clear you are wanting the selected values. Like arraylist[listbox1.SelectedIndex], but be aware that the value will be -1 when there isn't a selected value. Also if there is more than one you'll have to use the SelectedIndicies and a loop.

Comment: thank you so much thats exactly what i was looking for, sorry i couldnt explain it better, i may still end up re-writing i like the dictionary method it would of made far more sense for me to use that at the start.